# Retry method execution on failure?

Tags: c#

I am working on an application that is required to be constantly running, and as a requirement should make multiple attempts for particular processes such as web API/database calls, just in case network connectivity goes down for a moment, or something similar.

In this case, I'm constantly having to write a basic algorithm:

```
for (int attempt = 0; i < Config.AttemptCount; i++) {
    try {
        doSomething...;
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log(e);
    } finally {
        if (Config.WaitTimeForRetry > 0)
            Thread.Sleep(Config.WaitTimeForRetry);
    }
}

return false;
```

This of course is the most basic example, but there are others where I'm returning actual objects, performing heavy operations, etc. I recently got the idea to make a single method that could perform this algorithm for me so I can focus on the overall functionality with each implementation instead. With that said, I present to you, a method I need a better name for, and probably needs a much better implementation, or should be replaced by something pre-existing if such a thing exists because I re-invent the wheel a lot, but none-the-less, it's here .

```
public static TOut RunProcessWithMultipleAttempts<TIn, TOut>(int numberOfAttempts, int waitTimeInMilliseconds, TIn input, Func<TIn, TOut> process) {
    TOut result = default;
    while (numberOfAttempts-- > 0) {
        try {
            result = process.Invoke(input);
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log(e);
        } finally {
            if (waitTimeInMilliseconds > 0)
                Thread.Sleep(waitTimeInMilliseconds);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

To use this, I would write a method that does the work I wish to be performed:

```
static int attempts = 0;
private static string TrySomething(int i) {
    for (int index = 0; index < i; index++)
        if (attempts++ < 2)
            throw new Exception("Your request was denied.");

    return "Your request was successful.";
}
```

I would then utilize the `RunProcessWithMultipleAttempts` method to execute it:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine(RunProcessWithMultipleAttempts(3, 1000, 10, TrySomething));

    // Prevent the console from closing.
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

In this example, replace the `Log(e)` call with `Console.WriteLine(e)` to allow it to work on your local machine.

---

A few questions in my mind:

- How hard is this to scale?
- What are the downsides to this method?
- What alternatives are available?
- Is this code easy to understand?
- Not only in final usage, but initial implementation?

Oh, and perhaps my biggest question if I were to keep this implementation around:

> What would a more concise and clear name be for this method?

Comment: I'd highly recommend using [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) which solves this particular use case and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How hard is this to scale?

Sorry but I don't understand what do you mean here. How do you want to scale a method?

#### What are the downsides to this method?

- It does not work with `Action`
- It does not work with `Func<T1, T2, TResult>`
- It does not work with `Func<Task>`
- It does not work with `Func<Task<T>>`
- It blocks the calling thread unnecessary (`Thread.Sleep`)
- You must throw exception to enforce retry (can't use any other condition, like `Result != true`)
- It swallows the exception

  - in the worst case if all attempts fail then it will return a `default` instead of the exception
- It does not allow to use exponential back-off algorithm
- It does not allow infinite retry (performing yet another attempt until it succeeds)
- It does not utilize *Cancellation* concept
- It does not provide debug information (like how many times the retry has been performed)

#### What alternatives are available?

- [Polly's Retry](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry) << The suggested
- [EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Core](https://github.com/Dixin/EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Core)

#### Is this code easy to understand?

For me, yes.

#### Not only in final usage, but initial implementation?

Is this a question?

#### What would a more concise and clear name be for this method?

- `ExecuteWithRetry`
- `ExecuteAtMostNTimes`
- `RetryFunction`
- `PerformCallWithRetryPolicy`
- etc.

Comment: To start properly, thank you for the feedback! To answer some of your questions: Scalable, you answered this in the next section, just as I thought with how it doesn't implement `Action`, `Func<T1, T2, TResult>`, etc; Putting the thread to sleep was a defined requirement, which is the only reason it's there. The same rings true for swallowing the exception and preventing infinite retry. Throwing an exception was just for testing purposes, as ideally the executing functionality would succeed.

Comment: With that out of the way now, I need to read up on the links you sent, as well as exponential back-off. I like the idea of providing the debug information too. Regarding the cancellation concept, are you referring to the caller cancelling the execution? Thank you again for all of your time! This was an awesome answer!

Comment: @Taco The cancellation token can help you to stop the execution at any point. For example you can define a global timeout, if the threshold is exceeded then no further retry should be instantiated. Or you can provide a button on a UI to allow user cancellation. Or you can combine several tokens. etc.